# What does lag(log(emp), 1:2) mean when using pgmm function?

Tags: r, lag, plm

I tried an example regarding pgmm function in plm package. The codes are as follows:

```
library(plm)
data("EmplUK", package = "plm")

## Arellano and Bond (1991), table 4 col. b 
z1 <- pgmm(log(emp) ~ lag(log(emp), 1:2) + lag(log(wage), 0:1)
           + log(capital) + lag(log(output), 0:1) | lag(log(emp), 2:99),
            data = EmplUK, effect = "twoways", model = "twosteps")
summary(z1, robust = FALSE)
```

I am not sure the meaning of `lag(log(emp), 1:2)` and also `lag(log(emp), 2:99)`. Does `lag(log(emp), 1:2)` mean that from one unit to two unit lag value of `log(emp)` and `lag(log(emp), 2:99)` from two units to 99 units' lag value of log(emp)?

And also sometimes I got an error when running the regression in summary part but sometimes there was no such error (the codes are the same): 
`Error in !class_ind : invalid argument type`

Can anyone help me with these problems?[That's the error here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uA4v1.png)

Comment: Can you further clarify when that error occurs (a reproducible example)? `class_ind` does not appear in plm` source code at all.

Comment: I don't know why it happens to me sometimes. Just now I tried these same codes again without any modification or so, this error occurs. I thought it occurs to the summary part.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. After I restart R, it is fine again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`log`, a base R function, gives you the (natural) logarithm, in this case of variable `emp`.

`lag` of package `plm` can be given a second argument, called `k`, like in your example. By looking at `?plm::lag.plm` it becomes clear: `k` is

> an integer, the number of lags for the lag and lead methods (can also
>   be negative). For the lag method, a positive (negative) k gives lagged
>   (leading) values. For the lead method, a positive (negative) k gives
>   leading (lagged) values, thus, lag(x, k = -1) yields the same as
>   lead(x, k = 1). If k is an integer with length > 1 (k = c(k1, k2,
>   ...)), a matrix with multiple lagged pseries is returned

Thus, instead of typing `lag` twice to have the first and second lag:

(`lag(<your_variable>, 1)`
`lag(<your_variable>, 2)`

one can simply type

`lag(<your_variable>, k = 1:2)`, or without the named argument

`lag(<your_variable>, 1:2)`.

Setting `k` to `2:99` gives you the 2nd to 99th lags.

The number refers to the number of time periods the lagging is applied to, not to the number of individuals (units) as the lagging is applied to all individuals.

You may want to run the example in `?plm::lag.plm` to aid understanding of that function.

Comment: So 2:99 includes 99th lag also? Thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Yes it does included the last specified lag, in your case the 99th.